# Creating a package of a Python/Kivy/KivyMd app with PyInstaller: kivy.factory.FactoryException - No class <MDTopAppBar> in module <kivymd.uix.toolbar>

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying to create a package of a [**Python/KivyMD**](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/) app with [**PyInstaller**](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/index.html) for Windows systems.
After having modified the *spec file* as suggested in [Kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html), I tried to execute the exe file generated by *PyInstaller* getting this error:

```
kivy.factory.FactoryException: No class named <MDTopAppBar> in module <kivymd.uix.toolbar>
[20136] Failed to execute script 'MyScriptName' due to unhandled exception!
```

Actually, I'm not directly importing that dependency in my *.py* file: I directly use the *MDTopAppBar* widget in the *KV string* that defines the UI.
These are the versions of the main packages:

```
kivy                      2.1.0
kivy-deps-angle           0.3.3
kivy-deps-glew            0.3.1
kivy-deps-gstreamer       0.3.3
kivy-deps-sdl2            0.4.5
kivy-examples             2.1.0
kivy-garden               0.1.5
kivymd                    1.1.1
pyinstaller               5.5
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2022.10
python                    3.7.10
python-dateutil           2.8.2
python_abi                3.7
```

How can I prevent the raise of that exception?

Comment: Try adding `hiddenimports=['kivymd.uix.toolbar.toolbar.MDTopAppBar']` to your spec file.

Comment: Solved adding _MDTopAppBar_ to the imports of the Python script.